# Caching Facebook Like Box?

Tags: facebook, caching, facebook-like

I'm using the Like Box code from Facebook and I noticed it hinders my page load. After looking in Firebug it loads a bunch of Javascript and CSS files. I'm wondering is there a way to cache the Facebook Like box? I did search Google but the only one I saw was for Wordpress. I'm using php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a way to do this: Use channel file and cache it as much as possible. Read more about it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/)

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to actually code this? I get lost in the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I used @Martin link to find this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

The following code was modified to fit my situation, but I am not sure how much quicker it is or if the cache is working properly.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.php', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
```

My channel.php looks like this, also from the same page:

```
 <?php
 $cache_expire = 60*60*24*365;
 header("Pragma: public");
 header("Cache-Control: max-age=".$cache_expire);
 header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$cache_expire) . ' GMT');
 ?>
 <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Hope that helps add to the solution.